# Rewrite URL with htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost

I've searched through countless blogs and looked at stack overflow questions about this and I still just don't understand it.

What I have is a blog website with the url as:

```
http://website.local.co.uk/article.php?id=123-123
```

But I want to use mod rewrite to change it to:

```
http://website.local.co.uk/article/123-123
```

I'd also like to add a title to this to become:

```
http://website.local.co.uk/article/123-123/the-title-goes-here
```

Currently I am using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/?$ article.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

But this keeps redirecting me back to error 404 page as it's not picking up the ID number.  Any ideas how to achieve what I want it to do?

Answer (score 1):

Normally this can be done effectively using a router. Look up PHP Router on github, there are some useful router classes there. Also, routers usually come as part of a MVC framework such as CakePHP or Laravel. You can even use a micro-framework such as Slim or Flight.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+-[0-9]+) /article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: What about the `title` parameter?

Comment: Title is optional and OP can doesn't want title part in rewritten URL as you can see from question. Regex here allows OP to keep links as `/article/123-123/the-title` OR `/article/123-123/`

Comment: You're right, but it's unclear if the title should be added to the ID.  If a framework is used and it uses the ID param, you don't want to add a title to it right?

Comment: Yes it appears OP wants to keep links as Stackoverflow where question id is the driving factor and article is looked up from DB (if missing)

Comment: @anubhava I've edited my question to show the code that I'm using - Any ideas why it's not picking up the ID number and redirecting me back to an error page?

Comment: I checked your rule and it is failing due to wrong regex. If you replace your rule with my suggested rule then it will work fine.